# jQuery image loop not displaying any images

Tags: jquery, html, web

I'm trying to create a very basic image gallery in jQuery. The goal is to have 3 images fade in and out in a sequential order. So image 1 is displayed, fades to image 2 etc. then the whole thing loops again.

My HTML code so far is as follows:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Slider</title>
<style type="text/css">

.slider{
  width: 2848px;
  height: 2136px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.slider img{
  width:2848px;
  height:2136px;
  display:none;
}

</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Slider2.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="Slider2"();>
<div class="slider">
        <img id="1" src="31.jpg" border="0" alt="city"/>
        <img id="2" src="2vrtigo2.jpg" border="0" alt="roof"/>
        <img id="3" src="3.jpg" border="0" alt="sea"/>
</div>
</body>
```

And the jQuery code looks like this:

```
function Slider2()
{
var total = $(".slider img").size();

for (i=1; i<=total; i+=1)
{
    $(".slider #"+i).fadeIn(600);
    $(".slider #"+i).delay(2000).hide;  
}}
```

A quick syntactical note, I've also tried using i++ in the last argument of the For Loop. The result of this code is a blank, white page. I know some of the HTML is being compiled because the enormous 2848x2136 div creates scroll bars on the browser.

If anyone could help me out, that would be greatly appreciated. Obviously I'm relatively new to web programming and would love some insight into why this isn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Nelsons answer for syntax issues but also your logic is all wrong, your jquery will show all images at once, you need to introduce a multiplier in your delay.

The reason you need a multiplier in your delay is that when you loop through the elements in your for loop it doesn't run the loop for i=1 then wait for it to finish before running the loop for i=2, instead it runs them all within a few milliseconds, in order for the animations to run one after the other you need to delay each animation by an increased amount of time. In the code I have edited, all the fadeIns happen at once, there is then a different delay on each image before the fadeOut is triggered.

You seem to be getting mixed up between hide() / show() and fadeIn() / fadeOut():
hide() / show() act on an elements display property, setting it to either none or block. 
fadeIn() / fadeOut() act on an elements opacity setting , animating it between 0 and 1.
You need to pick one thing to change.

I have something like what you want working on js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mgu7/1/

Sorry I messed with your code because js fiddle didnt seem to trigger the onload function and I needed images that fit on the screen -  also please be aware that what I have done will not work properly either since I have not accounted for fadin/out times in my delay so there is an overlap in the animation that will get worse over time - but thats something for you to play with.:

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Slider</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <img id="img1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/dddddd" border="0" alt="city"/>
        <img id="img2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/444444" border="0" alt="roof"/>
        <img id="img3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/111111" border="0" alt="sea"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.slider{   
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
    display:block;    
}  
.slider img{   
    width:350px;   
    height:150px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total = $(".slider img").size();
    for (i=1; i<=total; i++)
    {
        $(".slider #img"+i).fadeIn(600).delay(2000*i).fadeOut(600);        
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation, I've made the relevant changes to my code and it's working as it should do now, so thanks a lot for clearing that up! A quick question if you don't mind, what does the multiplier do to make this work?

Comment: I have update my answer and tried to explain the purpose of the delay multiplier. happy coding.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. You've greatly helped my understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You lack the ending params of the method `hide()`:

```
$(".slider #"+i).delay(2000).hide;
                                 ^^---Here, must be hide()
```

Also you can write that two lines as a single one, like this:

```
$(".slider #"+i).fadeIn(600).delay(2000).hide();
```

**UPDATE:**
Also, your following line:

```
<body onload="Slider2"();>
```

should be like this:

```
<body onload="Slider2();">
```

Comment: Note also that starting an ID with a number is invalid HTML

Comment: Thanks for that, I've changed the code to your one-line suggestion, however I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: @user1871097 I've updated my answer with a new spotted error.

Comment: @Nelson thanks again for spotting that, I feel lazy for not noticing these! The page is still just rendering blank though.